# How Can move the text and ImageView Programatically in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I`m trying to move left, or right the text and ImageView on Android Studio, but I want to do this programatically.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("new title");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.bible1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Are you calling `getActionBar().setTitle("new title");` or `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("new title");`

Comment: I`m calling getActionBar().setTitle("new title");

Comment: Use this. getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");

Comment: try, getSupportActionBar().setTitle() instead

Comment: I tried it. Now it doesn't crash anymore, but It doesn't show the text. There's image only in the middle of the ActionBar.

Comment: I just put another image and the text is there, but it is too much in the right, and I can't see it fully. Do you know how can I arrange the text and Image programatically?

Comment: setTitle()? Try that?

Comment: So, I want to move the image to Left, and Text to left. Like in android studio android:layout_marginLeft="15dp", but I want to make this programatically... with the code that I opened this thread.